# Implementing model constant as list or enum in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model constant which is basically the values of `environments` as below:

```
class Account
  has_many :account_configs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :account_configs
  ACCOUNT_ENVS = %w[development staging production].freeze
end

class AccountConfig
  validates :account, presence: true
  validates :environment, inclusion: {in: Account::ACCOUNT_ENVS}
end
```

The constant `ACCOUNT_ENVS` is also used in `view`. Right now this is working well for my case but should I use `enum` here? If yes, how can I use it?

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html - I think you should go through this. It has clear steps on how to use enums.

Comment: Ok. So is `enum` the way to go here instead of  `array freeze`?

Comment: No hard and fast rule as such. But yes, its a good way. Storing integers and comparing them is lighter for the database.

Comment: Oh ok. Got it! Thank you.

Comment: As Alok said it really depends if you want to store an integer or string. Storing a string means looking directly at the database provides the correct answer.

Comment: You can use strings as values with ActiveRecord::Enum if you really want to. Just explicitly declare the mapping. `enum status: { development: 'development', staging: 'staging', production: 'production' }`.

Comment: To add to the confusion Postgres also has [native enumerated types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html).

Answer (score 0):

Using an `enum` (`integer`) is more performant, but it means *other people/applications* looking at your database need to know how to interpret the value.

Using a `string` is less performant, but it means *other people/applications* can immediately understand what the value means.

*How much* more performant is one vs the other? It depends on your use case; there is no simple answer here. You can try benchmarking it, but for most applications it likely won't make a big difference.

Which option is *better*? Again, there is no concrete answer; it depends on your use case. In particular, see the above comment about other people/applications viewing the same database.

Know the pros and cons of both approaches, and choose for yourself which is best.

Answer (score 0):

You can have following migration,

```
class ChangeEnvironmentOfAccountConfig < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :account_configs, :environment, :integer, default: 0
  end
end
```

Default is always set to `development`.

In model,

```
class AccountConfig
  enum environment: %w(:development, :staging, :production)
end

config = AccountConfig.create

config.environment
# => "development"

config.production?
# => false

config.production! #updates the object

AccountConfig.development # acts as scope to filter with environment
```